# Unique element of a named list

Tags: r, list, purrr

is there a way to return only unique elements of named list

```r
l <- list(x = c(1, 2), x = c(1, 2), x = c(1, 3), y = c(1,3))
# with unique, it doesn't work. it drops names
```

I'd like the output to be

```r
list(x = c(1, 2), x = c(1,3), y = c(1,3))
```

For now, using

```
l %>%
    tibble::enframe() %>%
    dplyr::distinct() %>%
    tibble::deframe()
```

but it is slow and requires a lot of calculation.

It seems that is close, but drops the second x item

```r
# Partial solution on stack overflow
l[!duplicated(l)]
list(x = c(1,2), y = c(1,3)
```

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `duplicated` on the names too:

```r
l[!(duplicated(l) & duplicated(names(l)))]

# $x
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $x
# [1] 1 3
# 
# $y
# [1] 1 3
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Good trick! The speedup is very considerable! 374.5µs  for to tidyverse solution and 12.9µs  for this one!

Comment: If you wanna go fast, you cna also check `collapse::fduplicated`

Comment: Will check it out